# Java: ¿Cómo guardar archivos fuera del contenedor de docker?

Tags: java, linux, docker

Quisiera saber si es posible y cómo guardar archivos fuera del contenedor de docker.
Esta desplegado sobre Centos 7.
El código que utilizo para guardar un archvivo es el siguiente

```
try ( FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = 
        new FileOutputStream("/var/www/html/assets/file 3.pdf")) {
    fileOutputStream1.write(bytes);
    System.out.println("Archivo creado...");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error al guardar: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Ahí le estoy indicando que lo guarde en la carpea **/var/www/html/assets/**, en este mismo servidor linux tengo apache instalado y ahí correrá una web por ello quería aprovechar que el back guarde los archivos directamente en esa carpeta y evitar tener que enviar flujos de bytes al front.

Sin embargo cuando se guarda el archivo, este lo hace en una ubicación distinta a la indicada, soy nuevo en esto de docker, según leí y entiendo, lo está guardando en el contendor donde se creó la imagen.
Busqué el archivo y si está pero en otra ubicación adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación [Manage data in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/), si quieres almacenar archivos en algún lugar del sistema de archivos del *host*, fuera de la carpeta dónde está/n montado/s el/los *volumen/es* de docker, tu opción es hacer un *bind mount*:

> **Bind mounts** may be stored **anywhere on the host system**. They may even be important system files or directories. Non-Docker processes on the Docker host or a Docker container can modify them at any time.

Mi traducción libre:

> Los ***bind mounts*** se pueden almacenar en **cualquier parte del sistema *host***. Incluso pueden ser archivos o directorios importantes del sistema. Los procesos que no son de Docker en el *host* de Docker o en un contenedor de Docker pueden modificarlos en cualquier momento.

En la misma documentación hay una advertencia importante:

> One side effect of using bind mounts, for better or for worse, is that you can change the host filesystem via processes running in a container, including creating, modifying, or deleting important system files or directories. This is a powerful ability which can have security implications, including impacting non-Docker processes on the host system.

Y no olvidemos que, una de las razones por las que usamos un contenedor es porque actúa como un *sandbox*, es decir, lo que se ejecute adentro está contenido y aislado del host.

Para montar un [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) puedes valerte del parámetro `--mount` a la hora de lanzar el contenedor. `mount` recibe una serie de *tuplas* en forma de `llave=valor`, las esenciales son:

- `type`, cuyo valor debe ser `bind`
- `source` es la ruta en el *host*
- `target` es la ruta dentro del contenedor

Encontrarás más información en la [documentación de bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Por ejemplo, para lanzar un contenedor donde lo que *almacenes* dentro de la ruta `\mnt\assets` quede dentro de la ruta `/var/www/html/assets` del *host*, lo harías con un comando como este:

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name prueba \
  --mount type=bind,source=/var/www/html/assets,target=/mnt/assets \
  nginx:latest
```

Debes recordar que

- El contenedor tendrá acceso a los archivos que se encuentren en esa carpeta en el host.
- Varios contenedores podrían compartir el acceso a dicha carpeta.
- El punto de montaje dentro del contenedor debe estar vacío
- La ruta no tiene por que ser la misma en el *host* que dentro del contenedor.

En el ejemplo propuesto, tendrías que ajustar tu código para usar la nueva ruta:

```
try ( FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = 
        new FileOutputStream("/mnt/assets/file 3.pdf")) {
```

Lo he hecho así, pensando que quizás dentro del contenedor esa ruta se utilice para algo más y tenga otros archivos necesarios para tu aplicación.

Comment: he seguido esos pasos y otros más que están en la documentación y aún no logro resolver el problema, mi duda es **mount type=bind,source=/var/www/html/assets,target=/mnt/asset** de donde saco el **target**? como sé cual es la ruta donde mi aplicativo guarda los archivos, he visto que los mete en el contenedor dentro una carpeta merged pero ni idea de por qué ahí y tampoco sé como cambiarlo

Comment: por lo cansada que estoy no vi esto `try ( FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = 
        new FileOutputStream("/mnt/assets/file 3.pdf"))` , ahí le indicas el target, o bueno eso entiendo, no quisiera mecanizarme con esto, pero funcionó! muchísimas gracias.

Comment: El _target_ es simplemente una ruta dónde se va a reflejar esa carpeta dentro del sistema de archivos del contenedor. La ruta tiene que existir hasta la penúltima sub-carpeta. Yo la he puesto dentro de `/mnt` por convención, pues allí suelen ponerse los puntos de montaje de dispositivos externos o rutas remotas , pero no tiene que estar allí necesariamente, puede ser dentro de cualquier ruta.